# Data transfer across big and small Endian machines

Tags: c, char, endianness

Assuming there are 3 strings like "cat", "bat, "rat". I need to combine them into one string and send them to another computer of different Endianess through socket programming.

So, if the other machine is big endian, I'll pack the strings as:
`memcpy (base, "cat", 3)`
`memcpy (base+3, "bat", 3)`
`memcpy (base+6, "rat", 3)`

If the other machine is little endian, I'll pack the strings as:
`memcpy (base, "rat", 3)`
`memcpy (base+3, "bat", 3)`
`memcpy (base+6, "cat", 3)`

***Is my method correct?***

***Secondly, will they be actually received on the other machine in a reverse order? I mean when the other machine's software  will start extracting strings from the "base" string, will it actually be in the reverse order - like rat, bat, cat?***

Comment: Why have you reversed the order of your three strings? Endian is about the order of bytes in integers and floats. It doesn't change the order of characters in strings (though it can affect the order of bytes in a character, e.g. UTF-16). It doesn't affect the order of things in larger collections. If swapping endianness meant everything was reversed, causality would be broken - you'd need to send tomorrows e-mails before you could send todays (each e-mail is just a string, and your inbox is just a collection of those strings).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you dump a memory buffer with two bytes `0x02 0x00` in it into a socket, the `0x02` is sent first, then `0x00` is sent. When a receiver reads from a socket, `0x02` will arrive first, and will be stored at the start of the buffer. `0x00` arrives second, and is stored right after `0x02`. So, after you did `send(sock, &buffer, 2)`, and receiver did `recv(sock, &buffer, 2)`, the contents of your and the receiver's `buffer`s are the same — on byte level.

But now a problem of interpretation comes in. Yeah, you have two bytes, `0x02 0x00`, in memory, but so what? What do they mean? Oh, they mean an integer number from `0..65535` range, you say? But there are two ways to store such a number. The first is to store more significant bits in the first byte, so `512 = 10'00000000` is stored as `0x02 0x00`. The second is to store less significant bits in the first byte, so `512` is stored as `0x00 0x02`, and `0x02 0x00` is a way to store `2`, not `512`.

So, the imprtant lesson is: when you send some data, you have to be sure that the receiver will interpret them just as you do. Integers that span multiple bytes can be interpreted differently, so you have to somehow make out an agreement on exactly one way to send them.

Now, back to character strings. A string in C is a sequence of bytes both on conceptual and representational level—that's not so with integers! When you work with integers, I bet you don't much care that they are represented as a bunch of bytes, and the actual representation is not specified by C. Your compiler may store integers in whatever fashion it desires. A string, however, *is* a sequence of bytes in a certain order, and that's fixed in C. You have the first character, the second, and so on. So there is just one way to interpret `02 00` as a string: it's a 2-character string with the first character `0x02`, and the second character `0x00`. No confusion is possible.

P.S. Of course, when you start thinking of strings not as a sequence of bytes, but a sequence of *characters*, the problem with intepretation arises again: which byte means what character? But that's another story.

**EDIT**: In your comment to another answer, you said that you "have to make a provision for the other machine to know that what I have sent is actually an integer not a string". Yes. That's the main problem with exchanging data with other machines: what you send and what they see is just a sequence of bytes. Now all participants of this exchange must interpret this sequence of bytes in the same way, or they get confused. If you mean to send number `512` and do this by sending bytes `0x02 0x00`, the other side better understand that by `0x02 0x00` you mean `512` and not `2`, or, say `START OF TEXT`. Or that when you send `0x31 0x32 0x33 0x00` you mean `"123"`, and not `825373440`, or `31323300`.

Still, the answer to the original question: "if I send `"catbatrat"`, what will sender see?" is: "the sender will see `"catbatrat"`, independent on endianness".

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. will study it and follow up soon.

Comment: So, this function of GCC `__builtin_bswap32` will do this conversion "automatically" for integers (for example)? But, this solution is compiler dependent? Secondly, if we need to do it manually, we actually need to "shift the bits" by << and >> operator? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: But how are you going to determine your current endianness? Besides, there are library functions `ntohl()`/`htonl()`/`ntohs()`/`htons()`. `ntohl()` takes `long`, assumes it is in big-endian format and converts it into your machine's native format ("ntoh" stands for "Network to Host"). `htonl()` takes `long`, and does the opposite ("hton" stands for "Host to Network"). On little-endian machines, these functions call `bswap` or something like this. On big-endian machines, they do nothing. But you need to use this functions only when you send integers over the wire, strings are okay without them.

Answer (score 3):

Endianness makes no difference at the byte level, so you don't need to worry about it for strings of 8 bit characters or anything else where the data is just a stream of bytes.

For anything where the elements are larger than a byte, e.g. 2 or more byte integers, floating point, etc, then you do need to worry about endianness, or alternatively use a text-based format for data interchange.

Comment: At what level does it make a difference then? What needs to be "converted" before passing on to other machine?

Comment: For anything larger than a byte, e.g. 2 or more byte integers, floating point, etc.

Comment: @ Anisha Kaul: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) coverages endianness very well.

Comment: Did you also mean to say that if a string is of (for example) ***4*** bytes, then the conversion is needed?

Comment: No, because the *elements* of a 4 byte string are still just bytes.

Comment: What did you mean by `alternatively use a text-based format for data interchange.`? Foe example I have to transfer an integer of 4 bytes, then what should I do?

Comment: Convert integer to string and then send it? But then I will also have to make a provision for the other machine to know that what I have sent is actually an integer not a string?

Comment: Yes, you just send e.g. "1234" instead of the integer 1234 in raw binary - that way you don't need to worry about endianness. For more complex data you can use e.g. XML or JSON to make things more robust and backward-compatible.

Comment: Pardon - I am a new comer: This is to be done using C language, so when you say - `you just send e.g. "1234" instead of the integer 1234 in **raw binary**` did you talk about the integer to string conversion and then sending?

Comment: Yes, convert the integer 1234 (binary) to a string, "1234", and send the string. This is really basic stuff so you might want to consider reading a couple of introductory books and tutorials on C and on programming in general.

Comment: @PaulR I know about converting int to string but wasn't sure about what did you mean by "raw binary", hence asked. Anyways, you also mentioned XML. XML is for storing data AFAIK. how would that be helpful here? Some hints?

Comment: Like I said, this is really basic stuff - it would be a good idea to do some background reading if you're completely knew to programming etc. Anyway, storage and networking are very similar - XML (and JSON etc) are often used for exchanging data over networks. Using a standard format means you can use standard libraries and you can cope with changes to the data format in a robust way (using raw binary without any formatting is very brittle when it comes to making changes).